# Thinktecture Authorization Server TokenRequestValidator returns 'Anonymous Client'

Tags: oauth-2.0, restful-authentication, postman, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture

I have an interesting problem.  We have set up the **Thinktecture Authorization Server** from the trusty Identity Server 2 and gotten it to work a few months back.  It is configured as a relying party for an already existing corporate identity server, so when we use the Code Flow example, click the `"Start authorization handshake"` we bounce over to the identity server, supply our credentials and get bounced back to the callback of the code flow with an access code, click the `Get Token`, and are granted with this fine `jwt token`.  All seems fine.

[image]

[image]

However,
When we try this either from, for instance, **postman**, or our app development team from their **development devices (android and iphone)**, it starts fine but when we call the token endpoint with our newly minted access code we get an `"Anonymous client"` response.

[image]

Looking at the web example from the **CodeFlow example** I see it posts basic authentication including a base64 value of the secret wich is missing from **postman** and our app team.  I see no reference to this in the **CodeFlow example** so I have no idea where this comes from. If I hard code the `Authorization BASIC` [including the Base64 secret I snatched from the previous example] it does not change anything.

We'be been stuck for several days on this so any help would be gratefully appreciated.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of recearch and hair pulling it seems the Postman client we are using does **not support Code Flow** and therefore does **not include the Authorisation header** we are missing.  After capturing the traffic from Postman with Fiddler we manually added the basic authorization header with the client name and secret and got everything working. So as of now, postman does not work.

I hope postman does add support for codeflow in the future.

Atli